# How to reference different locations inside a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

I am trying to access settings and values/functions from within other functions in JavaScript, and believe there is probably a simple rule which I am missing.  Here is a very simplified code example:

```
function h(){
    // example settings I want to declare for h()
    this.settings = {
        critical: 400,
        readCritical: function(){
            return this.settings.critical; // /!\ but this does not work
        }
    }
    this.hsub = function(){
        return this.settings.critical; // /!\ this does not work either
    }

}
var x = new h();
console.log(x.settings.critical); // This works fine
console.log(x.settings.readCritical()); // I can *call* this fine, but it can't read outside itself
console.log(x.hsub()); // I can also call this but same problem
console.log(h.settings); // `undefined`; I understand I can't see directly into the function
```

You can see the `this.settings.critical` value, which I'm trying to access from inside the respective functions `readCritical` and `hsub`.  How can I do this?  Specifically from the instantiated `x`.

Also a secondary question but related, I would prefer to declare `var settings = {}` instead of `this.settings`.  Is this possible or preferable?

Comment: What do you want `h.settings` to return? Do you consider the settings of all instances to be exactly the same? Because now some instance can differentiate with `x.settings.critical = 200`. So then you have some with 200, some with 400, and what would `h.settings.critical` then have to be? Also *why* do you prefer `var settings`? How would you then expose `settings`?

Comment: Lots of questions, but `h.settings` is an object and shouldn't return anything - but I would like `x.settings.something` to _perhaps_ return a value.  More often though I just want to _call_ `h()` to attach event bindings to an element, not actively work with `x`.  As far as instantiation, in my mind that's the test of writing the code well if you _could_ have multiple instances work OK independently.  As far a preferring `var settings`, I have written it that way in the past but with the accepted answer, I think using `this` is just as good.

Comment: You are looking for the singleton pattern? NB: currently `h.settings` does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only change you need to make is to remove `.settings` from within the `readCritical` function.

The `hsub` works as is. Not sure why you thought there was a problem

```js
function h(){
    this.settings = {
        critical: 400,
        readCritical: function(){
            return this.critical; // reference `critical` directly
        }
    }
    this.hsub = function(){
        return this.settings.critical; // this works just fine
    }

}

var x = new h();

console.log(x.settings.critical);       // 400
console.log(x.settings.readCritical()); // 400
console.log(x.hsub());                  // 400

// This is expected to be `undefined`
console.log(h.settings);
```

Comment: Thank you, that difference between where `readCritical()` needs to look for it and `hsub()` needs to look, on a small code snippet, is very instructive I hope for some future reader!  It was for me.  This seems to be the simplest application of my question using the fewest lines of code.

Comment: You're welcome. The value of `this` is generally defined by the caller. You can usually just look to the left of the `.` separating the object and method being invoked to determine what `this` will be. But if you detach them before calling, that would be different. `var fn = x.settings.readCritical; x();` Now `x` references `readCritical` but has no connection to `settings`.

Comment: @Me.Name: Correct. My comment above yours gives that warning. ;-)

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, another old classic closure problem.

There are two ways to solve it:

```
function h(){
    var self = this;
    this.settings = {
        critical: 400;
        readCritical: function() {
            return self.settings.critical();    // otherwise this.settings will 'cover' `this`.
        }
   }
}

readCritical: () => this.settings.critical();    // arrow functions won't form a function scope
```

Comment: It's really not a closure problem. It's a problem of the value of `this`. Arrow functions definitely form a function scope. They just don't define a `this` binding.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `this` (and binding functions to set it) are much discussed topics in JS. However, you seem not to be looking for `this` specifically, but sharing variables, there's another alternative. All in all, there's no best answer, but since you would also like to declare `var settings = {}`: you actually can and have access to that local variable available inside the other functions.

```js
function h(){        
    var settings = { //var settings is a local variable of the function h (or instance of it). If ES6 is allowed 'let' or 'const' are preferrable
        critical: 400,
        readCritical: function(){
            return settings.critical;
        }
    };
    this.settings = settings; //this.settings is not the same variable as var settings, making this statement valid
    this.hsub = function(){
        return settings.critical; //the local (var) settings is used
    }
}

var x = new h();
console.log(x.settings.critical); 
console.log(x.settings.readCritical()); 
console.log(x.hsub());
```

Pitfall here, is that if the calling code changes `x.settings` to something else, the variables will not point to the same instance (if they change a value inside `x.settings`, all is well). If that is a risk, it could be exposed as a property method instead

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only want to have one instance. If that is so, then just create the instance immediately with an object literal notation:

```js
var h = {
    settings: {
        critical: 400,
        readCritical: function(){
            return this.critical;
        }
    },
    hsub: function(){
        return this.settings.critical;
    }
}
console.log(h.settings.critical);
console.log(h.settings.readCritical());
console.log(h.hsub());
console.log(h.settings);
```

Now all four property accesses work as expected when given the singleton object `h`.